# CodeSignal Different Squares More Efficiently

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, matrix, big-o

I'm trying to make my code more efficient. Please be honest and tell me how to fix it and if it is "spaghetti code."

CodeSignal Different Squares

> Given a rectangular matrix containing only digits, calculate the number of different 2 × 2 squares in it.
> Example:
> For matrix = 
> [[1, 2, 1],
>
>  [2, 2, 2],
>
> [2, 2, 2],
>
> [1, 2, 3],
>
> [2, 2, 1]]
>
> the output should be
> differentSquares(matrix) = 6.
> Here are all 6 different 2 × 2 squares:
>
> 1 2
>
> 2 2
>
> 2 1
>
> 2 2
>
> 2 2
>
> 2 2
>
> 2 2
>
> 1 2
>
> 2 2
>
> 2 3
>
> 2 3
>
> 2 1

My current code:

```
function differentSquares(matrix) {
  let smallSquares = [];

  for(let i = 0; i < matrix.length - 1; i++){
    buildCurr(matrix, i, smallSquares);
  }
  return smallSquares.length;
}
function compareArrs(smallSquares, currentSquare){
  let includes = smallSquares.find((arr) => arr.join("") === currentSquare.join(""));
  if(!includes){
    smallSquares.push(currentSquare);
  }            
}
function buildCurr(matrix, i, smallSquares){
  for(let j = 0; j < matrix[i].length - 1; j++){
    let currentSquare = [matrix[i][j], matrix[i][j+1], matrix[i+1][j], matrix[i+1][j+1]];
    compareArrs(smallSquares, currentSquare);
  }
}
```

The error I'm getting:

> Tests passed: 9/13. Execution time limit exceeded on test 10: Program exceeded the execution time limit. Make sure that it completes execution in a few seconds for any possible input.
> Click the "Run Tests" button to see output, console logs, and detailed error messages for sample or custom test cases. This information is hidden when clicking the "Submit" button in order to prevent hard-coding solutions to the hidden test cases.
>
> Sample tests:
> 7/7
>
> Hidden tests:
> 2/6
>
> Score:
> 167/300

I realize it probably has to do with O notation. It got better when I separated it into another function, and that's why I did it that way.

Comment: What about overlap top to bottom? Just side to side?

Comment: @StackSlave I'm sorry. I'm not exactly sure what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way, i'm using an array to store all the smallsquares as an string and using the "include" operation to look into this array for already existing values.

```
function differentSquares(matrix) {
  let smallSquares = [];
  var value = "";

  for(let i = 0; i < matrix.length - 1; i++){
      
    for(let j = 0; j < matrix[i].length - 1; j++){
        value = (`${matrix[i][j]}${matrix[i][j+1]}${matrix[i+1][j]}${matrix[i+1][j+1]}`)
        if(!smallSquares.includes(value)){
            smallSquares.push(value);
        }
    }
  }
  
  return smallSquares.length;
}
```

i hope it helps anyone looking for the answer too

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a set instead of an array

```
function differentSquares(matrix) {
    s = new Set()
    for (i = 0; i < matrix.length-1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < matrix[i].length-1; j++) {
            s.add([matrix[i][j], matrix[i][j+1], matrix[i+1][j], matrix[i+1][j+1]].toString())}}
    return s.size
}
```